# VbScript throwing an error "Unknown runtime error"

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I wrote a code to delete the rows from excel sheet,but it is giving me an error as mentioned in subject.

**CODE**

```
 Sub ChildPidDelt(ob3,DeletArr)

Dim height,row,str,i
Dim dataArray
Dim d
height = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ob3.Columns(1))
'MsgBox(height)
ReDim dataArray(height - 2, 0) ' -1 for 0 index, -1 for the first row as header row, excluded
str = ""
dataArray = ob3.Range(ob3.Cells(2, 1),ob3.Cells(height, 1)).Value
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
MsgBox(LBound(DeletArr) & ":" & UBound(DeletArr))
For i = LBound(DeletArr) To UBound(DeletArr)
    If Not d.exists(DeletArr(i)) Then
        d(DeletArr(i)) =  0
    End If
Next
MsgBox(LBound(dataArray,1) & ":" & UBound(dataArray,1))
For i = LBound(dataArray, 1) To UBound(dataArray, 1)
    If d.exists(dataArray(i, 1)) Then

        str = str & (i+1) & ":" & (i+1) & ","

    Else
        'found = False
    End If
Next
If Len(str) > 0 Then
    MsgBox(Len(str))
    str = Mid(str, 1, Len(str) - 1)
    MsgBox(str)
    ob3.Range(str).Delete

End If

End Sub
```

Please find the debug screens below:

[image: screen1]
[image: Screen2]
[image: Screen3]
[image: Screen4]
[image: Screen5]

Could you help me here by saying what the reason is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range()` cannot handle a string of more than 255 characters.

You can work around this issue by breaking your delete into pieces.  Here's a simple way to do it: place directly after your last msgbox

```
dim x
dim rangesToRemove
rangesToRemove = Split(str,",")
for x = UBOUND(rangesToRemove) to LBOUND(RangesToRemove) Step -1
   ob3.Range(rangesToRemove(x)).delete
next
```

Edit: Ok, due to your comment here's a much more complicated way that will break the delete up into chunks.

```
dim x
dim rangesToRemove
dim strToRemove : strToRemove = ""
rangesToRemove = Split(str,",")
for x = UBOUND(rangesToRemove) to LBOUND(RangesToRemove) Step -1
   strToRemove = strToRemove & rangesToRemove(x)
   If Len(strToRemove) > 200 then
       ob3.Range(strToRemove).delete
       strToRemove = ""
   else
       strToRemove = strToRemove & ","
   end if
next
If len(strToRemove) > 0 then
   strToRemove = Left(strToRemove, Len(strToRemove) -1)
   ob3.Range(strToRemove).delete
end if
```

Comment: This way removal of rows,can anyway delete the undesired row,as delete the causes the row up movement right? any faster process is there? it will delete one by one right?

Comment: Well, obviously you could break it up into chunks... I bothered to update to show a possible way of doing that.

Comment: Nice one, just to confirm- will it be `UBOUND(rangesToRemove)` or `UBOUND(rangesToRemove)-1`?

Comment: please see the revised code as you told,still i broke it more small chunk! but no improvement!